# How can I make a regex to test username complexity requirements?

Tags: php, regex

I'm learning about regular expressions and have one question; the answer will help me to understand regexes better.

The input is a username. This username should include at least 4 lower case chars (a-z), one upper char (A-Z) and 2 numbers. It should also have a maximum of 10 chars in total. How can I make a regular expression to test for these requirements?

Comment: That's an _extremely_ annoying limitation.  There is no reason to add complexity requirements for usernames.

Comment: A single regex can't accomplish this. Regexes are used for matching specific patterns, not statistical analysis. Counting 10 chars is easy with a regex, but saying "any N must be X" isn't a task for a regex. You would need more complicated program logic (i.e. at least 3 separate counters for this).

Comment: @SLaks: ceylan's motivations aren't important, this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: Not possible without multiple regular expressions or a really long and complex one that will be slow and not worth the trouble.  You would essentially write the regex to match any form of combination of the above requirements. so probably 10+ or's

Comment: thank you answers. but sure this is for just for practicing.

Comment: @Chris - really? Not possible? Can you see my asnwer. I would like to know if you consider it a valid regex or not for this question. Thanks!

Comment: @manojlds: yeah I see your answer, I still don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a regex with lookaheads / lookbehinds for each condition. Something like below:

```
^(?=(.*[a-z]){4})(?=.*[A-Z])(?=(.*\d){2}).{7,10}$
```

I think the regex is self explanatory, tell me if you want me to explain on each part.

Ok, explanation as per OP's request:

`(?=ABC)`,`(?!ABC)` and `(?<=ABC)`, `(?<!ABC)` - are lookaheads and lookbehinds that match groups before / after your expression and don't include them in the results. The one with `=` are positive and one with `!` are negative.

Here for example, `(?=(.*[a-z]){4})` ensures that the main expression (`.{7,10}`) has at least 4 lower case characters. Similarly, we have one for each condition. `.{7,10}` ensure max 10 ( minimum 7 - 4 lower + 1 upper + 2 digits )

Having such tightly constrained <strike>passwords</strike> (whoa usernames like this are even worse) is not recommended as @SLaks mentions, but makes for some good regex learning :) Also, regexes are not known for performance, especially a ginormous one.

Comment: I beg to differ.  That is not self-explanatory.

Comment: @ceylan - do not edit my answer to get a request :) Just add a comment like this. I have added some explanation. @SLaks - I have added some explanation. Thanks

Comment: @manojlds correct me if I'm wrong, but you're requiring 4 CONSECUTIVE lowercase characters, which isn't what the OP asked for. The question is asking for 4 lowercase OVERALL.

Comment: @Chris I am using `.*[a-z]` not just `[a-z]`

Comment: @manojlds: OK, point taken. But this isn't restricting the counts of the characters. It IS ensuring that there are at LEAST N characters of each class, but nothing in there is restricting it to 10 chars in length total.

Comment: thank you maonjlds. sorry for late reply. were having some issues with the browser. this is working with php. i never saw lookaheads in my practicing book before. do you know any good article/tutorial link?

Comment: @Chris - I have made it more explicit now. Basically the `.{7,10}` ensures there is maximum of 10. Again, example: http://regexr.com?2tp0b

Comment: @manojlds: I tip my hat to you sir. Very good, I had no idea you could do that.

Comment: @ceylan - I think this article is good -http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html . Another place to learn is here at stackoverflow :) Cheers!

Comment: manojlds, forget the multiple expressions. i just want to check if the string includes at least 4 lower chars(anywhere in the string,overall). tried (.*[a-z]){4}) this only from your pattern but didn't work. ) :/

Comment: @ceylan You should have it like this - `^(?=(.*[a-z]){4}).*$`

Comment: if(preg_match("#^(?=(.*[a-z]){4}).*$)#" tried this in php but not working. with compiler error: Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 20 in

Comment: @ceylan - you have a `)` after the `$`

Comment: ?= these chars are not covered in most of regex articles (specially in the books) is there any reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

It might be difficult to combine all those into a single regex expression because you don't have a set order.  You could look to see if php supports grouping constructs (lookahead/lookbehind) in regex expression as you might be able to use those.

Here is a link to the .net regex specification.  I know you are looking at php, but it should be more or less be similiar in terms of what types of pattern matching you can actually do.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx